# jquery mobile index page must be jsp or html

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-mobile, servlets

I am working on jquery mobile ,I want to ask that we should make our pages on jsp file or in html file. is there any difference in using any of the pages or can we use both type of pages. but one is client side and other is server side.

Answer (score 0):

An [HTML page](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/) will do the job.

If you open a .jsp file with HTML / jQuery content in your web browser, you can notice that the result is the same. If you need a jsp file for some reason then go with it.